# local variable 'stockqty' referenced before assignment in django

Tags: django

Please how do i resolve the error   local variable 'stockqty' referenced before assignment. I have a save method in one of my models that searches for an item and return some values like quantity, price, cost etc but i keep getting this error..

def save (self):

```
    callitems=Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName)

    for callitem in callitems:
        stockqty=callitem.quantity
        #stovkqty.append(callitem.quantity)
        price=callitem.unitprice
        #price.append(callitem.unitprice)
        cost=callitem.unitcost
        #cost.append(callitem.unitcost)
        vat=callitem.tax.rate
    if self.quantity < stockqty: the error complain is here
        if self.discount==True:
            self.total= self.discountprice * self.quantity
            self.profit=self.total-(cost * self.quantity)
            self.salesdate=date.today()
            self.salestime=datetime.now()
            self.staff='admin'
            Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName).update(quantity=stockqty-self.quantity)
        else:
            self.total= price * self.quantity
            self.profit=self.total-(cost * self.quantity)
            self.salesdate=date.today()
            self.salestime=datetime.now()
            self.staff='admin'
            Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName).update(quantity=stockqty-self.quantity)
    super(RecordSales, self).save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an indentation error. The first `if` statement should be inside the for loop, but it is "in parallel" to it. Try this:

```
callitems=Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName)

    for callitem in callitems:
        stockqty=callitem.quantity
        #stovkqty.append(callitem.quantity)
        price=callitem.unitprice
        #price.append(callitem.unitprice)
        cost=callitem.unitcost
        #cost.append(callitem.unitcost)
        vat=callitem.tax.rate
        if self.quantity < stockqty:    # the error complain is here
            if self.discount==True:
                self.total= self.discountprice * self.quantity
                self.profit=self.total-(cost * self.quantity)
                self.salesdate=date.today()
                self.salestime=datetime.now()
                self.staff='admin'
                Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName).update(quantity=stockqty-self.quantity)
            else:
                self.total= price * self.quantity
                self.profit=self.total-(cost * self.quantity)
                self.salesdate=date.today()
                self.salestime=datetime.now()
                self.staff='admin'
                Item.objects.filter(subcategory=self.ItemName).update(quantity=stockqty-self.quantity)
        super(RecordSales, self).save()
```

Comment: Better yet, replace the two consecutive `if`s with the following combined test: `if self.quantity < stockqty and self.discount` (notice that in python you don't need to use `if object == True:`, because non-null objects evaluate True, then you just use `if object:`